# Unicode Character search/modification

Tags: unicode

So I am trying to combine some unicode characters to create something like this white symbol. [image]

Currently I have ▝███ but am struggling to get anything closer.
https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+2580

Could anyone shed some light on the subject or provide other character combinations?
Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Maybe ■███  (`■███`) -combined  `■` (U+25A0,  *Black Square*) and  `█` (U+2588,  *Full Block*) or `￭███` (￭███)? You could try any of - `⏹` (U+23F9,  *BLACK SQUARE FOR STOP*)
- `■` (U+25A0,  *Black Square*)
- `⯀` (U+2BC0,  *BLACK SQUARE CENTRED*)
- `` (U+1F532, *BLACK SQUARE BUTTON (0xd83d,0xdd32)*)

Comment: Whether these work will depend a lot on the font used. If you control the font, you can create any ligature you like (or add a private codepoint). Unicode doesn't promise any particular glyph appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unicode characters you're looking for are in the [Symbols for Legacy Computing Block](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/symbols_for_legacy_computing/images.htm). These include 1/3 offsets to do what you're trying to do. These have extremely poor font support, however. I don't know of any font that includes glyphs for them. You'd probably have to provide your own, in which case you might do better using a private code point or a custom ligature.